# Combine List of scala case classes by time and construct new list of case class

Tags: scala, collections

```
trait MetaData {
    def time:DateTime
}

case class ImageMetadata(time: DateTime, name: String) extends MetaData
case class ObjectMetadata(time: DateTime, tags: List[String]) extends MetaData
case class ImageTypeMetadata(time: DateTime, name: String, tags: List[String])
```

I have a method which returns `Future[List[ImageMetadata]]` and `Future[List[ObjectMetadata]]`; I would like to combine these two lists by `time` field in `ImageMetadata` and `ObjectMetadata` and would like to construct `Future[List[ImageTypeMetadata]]`.

Can I have best possible options on this ?

Comment: What did you try? What happened? What did you expect to happen? What is DateTime, import ...?

Comment: Explain where you are stuck? What do you mean by "Can I have best possible options on this ?"

Comment: Are you waiting on all the futures simultaneously, and then combining the lists, or one of the futures is driving the process?

Comment: `DateTime` is `import org.joda.time.DateTime`. To simplify my question how I can combine `List[ImageMetadata]` and `List[ObjectMetadata]` to build `List[ImageTypeMetadata]` is what I am looking for. Need suggestions on what list functions i can use ?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you mean by "combine two lists by `time`". Suppose you have a `List` of 3 `ImageMetadata`, all with the same `time` value. And suppose you have a `List` of 2 `ObjectMetadata`, both with the same `time` as the first list. How should those be combined? Would the result be a list with six `ImageTypeMetadata` elements? Suppose no `time` member matched across either list? Would the result be an empty list? Example data with expected results would help.

Comment: @jwvh: Well, given a function (IMD, OMD)=>Option{ITMD], you can combine any two elements, and later filter the Nones, if imd.time didn't match omd.time. Or check the time upfront, and only produce ITMD if the times match. Since they end in a list, you may later filter for the first element of time, and control this by either first iterating over IMD, or OMD.

Comment: @LaxmikanthSamudrala: Didn't my 2nd code, with the quattro-map  work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is, how to combine two collections without Future:

Since my Scala lacks a DateTime, but I always need concrete examples for testing, I redifined DateTime as String. You wouldn't use that type declaration. :)

```
type DateTime=String

val la = List (ImageMetadata("12", "im 1 foo"), ImageMetadata ("13", "im 2 bar"), ImageMetadata ("23", "im 3 bar"))
val lb = List (ObjectMetadata("23", List ("o", "1")), ObjectMetadata ("12", List("o", "2")), ObjectMetadata ("17", List("o", "3")))

for (i <- la;
     o <- lb;
     if (i.time == o.time)) yield { ImageTypeMetadata (i.time, i.name, o.tags)}

res12: List[ImageTypeMetadata] = List(ImageTypeMetadata(12,im 1 foo,List(o, 2)), ImageTypeMetadata(23,im 3 bar,List(o, 1)))
```

Does that help, in doing the same with Futures of Lists?
Well, it is pretty straight forward:

```
type DateTime=String

sealed trait MetaData {
    def time:DateTime
}
case class ImageMetadata (time: DateTime, name: String) extends MetaData
case class ObjectMetadata (time: DateTime, tags: List[String]) extends MetaData
case class ImageTypeMetadata (time: DateTime, name: String, tags: List[String])

val la = List (ImageMetadata("12", "im 1 foo"), ImageMetadata ("13", "im 2 bar"), ImageMetadata ("23", "im 3 bar"))
val lb = List (ObjectMetadata("23", List ("o", "1")), ObjectMetadata ("12", List("o", "2")), ObjectMetadata ("17", List("o", "3")))

import concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val flim : Future [List [ImageMetadata]] = Future (la)
val flom : Future [List [ObjectMetadata]] = Future (lb)
flim.map (_.map (im => flom.map (_.map (om => {if (im.time == om.time)  Future (ImageTypeMetadata (im.time, im.name, om.tags))}))))
```